# how to increase height of TableViewCell according to content in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableView` and I want to display products in `UITableViewCell`.

Products can be multiple so I have to display products in this format attached in screenshot.

When there are multiple products, I want to expand height of that cell.

Suppose if one product so height will be default.

Height will change according to content.

How do I achieve this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am unclear what the problem is. Is the problem with Autolayout? Or is the problem to do with your data source? Or is it something else entirely different? The screenshot doesn't make clear what the problem is - can you create an extra image that shows how you want it to look?

Comment: problem is suppose my text is big in tableview it should adjust with height of tableview ios. screen shot indicates this is problem

Comment: i want self sizing cell

Comment: If you want a self-sizing cell you need to implement Autolayout on your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. There are various tutorials on the web and many questions on Stack Overflow about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you can calculate the height of text then add in cell hight 
like bellow

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var height:CGFloat = self.calculateHeightForString(messageArray[indexPath.row])
    return height 
}

func calculateHeightForString(inString:String) -> CGFloat
{
    var messageString = inString
    var attributes = [UIFont(): UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)]
    var attrString:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
    var rect:CGRect = attrString!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(300.0,CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil )//hear u will get nearer height not the exact value 
    var requredSize:CGRect = rect
    return requredSize.height  //to include button's in your tableview

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the self sizing, raywenderlich tutorial :
[self-sizing-cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)